# How to retrive image from a table and save it into a folder in different server using sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to retrive image from a table and save it into a folder in different server using sql query
The image is stored in DB as BLOB.

Comment: How the image stored in table. Please share the table structure as well.

Comment: `SET @imageVar = (SELECT column FROM table WHERE condition) INSERT table SET value = @imageVar;`. But it's impossible to help you 100% without table schema etc. If you have another language paired with your solution, it becomes infinately easier.

Comment: I was able to save image on the same server.But I want to save it on an another server.Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't perform a File System Operation using SQL Server alone. So If you want to save an Image Stored in SQL Server database as a File in your File System, Try using C# or any such Front End Languages to retrieve the Record from the Database and then Save to the Desired Location

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with PowerShell, here an example:

```
$connectionString = "Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=DATABASE;pwd=PASSWORD;User ID=USER;"
$sqlCommandText = "SELECT id, Photo, Photo_TypeMime FROM MYTABLE" #query
$saveToDir = "D:\" # output directory
$connection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection($connectionString)
$command = new-object System.Data.sqlclient.sqlcommand($sqlCommandText,$connection)
$connection.Open()
$bufferSize = 8192 #default value
$buffer = [array]::CreateInstance('Byte', $bufferSize)
$dr = $command.ExecuteReader()
While ($dr.Read())
{
    $ext = GetExtFromMimeType($dr.GetString(2)) # create a function to return extention from mime type if you don't have the file name saved in the database
    $fs = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($saveToDir + $dr.GetDecimal(0) + $ext), Create, Write #my example id is decimal but you can change it
    $bw = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter $fs
    $start = 0
    $received = $dr.GetBytes(1, $start, $buffer, 0, $bufferSize - 1)
    While ($received -gt 0)
    {
       $bw.Write($buffer, 0, $received)
       $bw.Flush()
       $start += $received
       # Read next byte stream
       $received = $dr.GetBytes(1, $start, $buffer, 0, $bufferSize - 1)
    }
    $bw.Close()
    $fs.Close()
}
$fs.Dispose()
$dr.Close()
$command.Dispose()
$connection.Close()
```

Also you can find a more detailed example here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/890.export-sql-server-blob-data-with-powershell.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use similar to this.

```
-- This will create format file, replace [TABLE_NAME_WITH_DATABASE] with your table and [SERVERNAME] with your server name
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp [TABLE_NAME_WITH_DATABASE] format null -S [SERVERNAME] -T -n -f c:\Test\PP.fmt' 

-- After this step you will see a format file,in that you have to delete all other columns except your image column
-- and run below query.
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT Photo FROM Server.Db.Table WHERE PK = 1" queryout C:\Test\ProductPhotoID_69.[IMAGE_EXTENSTION] -S [SERVERNAME] -T -f C:\Test\PP.fmt'
```

Comment: This will be executed on the remote server, it would work only if you want to save the image on the server that hosts the sql server instance

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Make sure the following statement is executed to enable file IO
-- From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191188.aspx
--------- --------- --------- --------- --------- --------- --------- 
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO

-- Write all database images (jpg) to file. The file path needs to exist and you'll need to concat ".jpg" to ImageFilename. 
--------- --------- --------- --------- --------- --------- --------- 
DECLARE CURSOR_ProductIds CURSOR FOR (SELECT ImgImagesId FROM ImgProductSample)

DECLARE @ProductId INT;

OPEN CURSOR_ProductIds

FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR_ProductIds INTO @ProductId
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
BEGIN
  DECLARE @ImageData varbinary(max);
  SELECT @ImageData = (SELECT convert(varbinary(max), ImageData, 1) FROM ProductImages WHERE Id = @ProductId);

  DECLARE @Path nvarchar(1024);
  SELECT @Path = 'C:\MyImages\Output';

  DECLARE @Filename NVARCHAR(1024);
  SELECT @Filename = (SELECT ImageFilename FROM ProductImages WHERE id = @ProductId);

  DECLARE @FullPathToOutputFile NVARCHAR(2048);
  SELECT @FullPathToOutputFile = @Path + '\' + @Filename;

  DECLARE @ObjectToken INT
  EXEC sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @ObjectToken OUTPUT;
  EXEC sp_OASetProperty @ObjectToken, 'Type', 1;
  EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Open';
  EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Write', NULL, @ImageData;
  EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'SaveToFile', NULL, @FullPathToOutputFile, 2;
  EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Close';
  EXEC sp_OADestroy @ObjectToken;

  FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR_ProductIds INTO @ProductId
END
CLOSE CURSOR_ProductIds
DEALLOCATE CURSOR_ProductIds
```